# Как добавить значение в переменную внутри словаря?

Tags: python, словари

У меня есть словарь и json. Мне нужно, чтобы при вводе команды(где item = test), словарь не перезаписывался, а дополнялся. Вот, что я хочу получить:

```py
data = {
        "item": "tester", "test", #tester - это предмет, который был, а test - предмет, который добавлен
        "amount": "1", "1"
    }
```

Вот мой говнокод:

```
    inv = {
        "item": "",
        "amount": ""
    }
    with open(f"file.json", "r") as write_file:
        data = json.load(write_file)
    with open(f"file.json", "w") as write_file:
        #Пытался сделать
        inv["item"] = item
        inv["amount"] =  num
        inv["item"] + data["item"]
        json.dump(inv, write_file) #Сохранение
```

Comment: это у вас вопрос, как словарь стандартно расширить? Точно не через `+`:-) Вот вам целая россыпь возможностей, если в этом вопрос: <https://docs-python.ru/tutorial/operatsii-slovarjami-dict-python/>, даже точнее: <https://docs-python.ru/tutorial/operatsii-slovarjami-dict-python/dobavlenie-izmenenie-elementa-slovarja-kljuchu/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Таким образом объединить данные по одному ключу нельзя, зато можно создать вместо словаря inv список и добавлять туда словари вида `{"item": x, "amount": y}` в блоке `with open(f"file.json", "w")`, либо поместить по ключам списки и добавлять значения уже туда методом .append() в том же блоке `with`, что-то вроде такого: `{"item": [x, y], "amount": [11, 22]}`